# combining two values from two different columns and print unique values and count of unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have a data frame where I have two columns and each column has 5 values each and I want to combine all values from the two columns and print all unique values and count number of unique values

Example

Column 1 - 'Fruits 1' - has values these values [Apple, Orange, Banana, Grapes, Mango]

Column 2 - 'Fruits 2' - has values these values [Apricot, Avocado, Blackberries, Grapes, Mango]

Now I want to combine values from both the columns and print all unique values and also want count of unique when both are combined

expected result = [Apple, Orange, Banana, Grapes, Mango, Apricot, Avocado, Blackberries]

Unique value count = 8

Please can anybody help me with the code

Comment: A Python set can do this easily.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `set` on the underlying numpy array:

```
set(df[['Fruits 1', 'Fruits 2']].values.ravel())
```

Output:

```
{'Apple',
 'Apricot',
 'Avocado',
 'Banana',
 'Blackberries',
 'Grapes',
 'Mango',
 'Orange'}
```

###### length:

```
len(set(df[['Fruits 1', 'Fruits 2']].values.ravel()))
```

Output: `8`